# ASP.NET/C# - HTML anchor won't Server.Transfer my page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a page (page_one) that when loads does a `Server.Transfer` to a different URL (page_two). When page_two loads it adds a bread crumb to the top of the page with an HTML anchor with it's `href` pointing to page_one, thinking page_two will load by clicking this link. Navigating away from this page then clicking on the page_one bread crumb should `Server.Transfer` to page_two but instead crashes. I fixed that problem by pointing the bread crumb `href` to page_two, but now clicking on this bread crumb changes my URL to page_two when I want it to read page_one. Any suggestions for fixing this?

**UPDATE** problem solved. Typo in the href, that's why the app crashed (i know, im a dumbass). also, i was just told the URL doesn't matter anyway and to link to the page directly.

Comment: Why don't you just have the html anchor function like it does by default and link to the page in it's href rather than going back to the server?

Comment: How important is the URL to the user?

Comment: "How important is the URL to the user?" You'll have to ask the app's original developer who I've never met. I was just told that the URL is not important at all, and to remove these Server.Transfer's and link directly to the page. problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

A server.transfer does NOT redirect the client browser.  All it does is internally execute a different page.  The browser will still think it's on the original page.

So, if you need the browser URL to change you'll have to do a Response.Redirect instead of a transfer, or, as antonlavey suggests, just let the link be a regular link and not cause a postback.